# Error while Inserting spark dataframe into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, pyspark

I am inserting spark dataframe into a Table in SQL Server Database using pyspark...

I am using pycharm as IDE,

here is my code snippet,

```
server_name = "SERVER"
database_name = "DB"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://{"+server_name+"} "+ ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

table_name = "Table_Temp"
username = "USER"
password = "PASS" 


df_target.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", username) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .save()
```

while executing the above snippet, I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\SCD2.py", line 129, in <module>
    df_target.write \
  File "E:\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 966, in save
  File "E:\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "E:\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
  File "E:\spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o198.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:864)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
```

I have installed Spark.
I Really dont know where I am going wrong...

Please help me...

Comment: Have you read through [Apache Spark connector: SQL Server & Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector) yet. Is Spark 3.3 a supported version?

Answer (score 0):

Current support from Microsoft restricts `write`/`overwrite`/`append` operations on SQL Server 2008+ only to **[Apache Spark 2.4.x, 3.0.x & 3.1.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16)**; while you're using Spark 3.3.1. Hence the error message!
[image]